# DRY initialization in Vues.js components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When a component is initialized I run the data callback like:

```
data(){
    return {
        name: myNameGetter(),
        age: myAgeGetter(),
        // etc...
    }
},
```

and then warn some parent component about logic from this component:

```
created(){
    this.$emit('personFullName', this.getFullName());
},
```

and then I also have the same logic inside my watchers:

```
watch: {
    person: function(){
        this.name = myNameGetter();
        this.age = myAgeGetter();
        this.$emit('personFullName', this.getFullName());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to DRY this?

The only idea I came up with was:

```
watch: {
    person: function(){
        const data = this.data();
        for (let key in data) this[key] = data[key];
        this.$emit('personFullName', this.getFullName());
    }
}
```

but feels a bit unDRY still. How does the community solved this?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about what your component actually does? Is it for editing a Person object? What are its props? Is `person` a prop? How does it work? This will help me to give you a suitable answer.

Comment: @DecadeMoon so that was a example, the real life app is a calendar. In the container I have the calendar header. Then I have child components for month, week and day view. The title in the container is set by the child component. So if its month view the child will `$emit` "march 2017", if its the day view the other child component will `$emit` "31st march". And so on. The problem is that I have to call that getter function in `data` when the component initialises, also on `watch` and emit that to parent when `created`. This is what I want to DRY.

Answer (score 0):

> so that was a example, the real life app is a calendar. In the container I have the calendar header. Then I have child components for month, week and day view. The title in the container is set by the child component. So if its month view the child will $emit "march 2017", if its the day view the other child component will $emit "31st march". And so on. The problem is that I have to call that getter function in data when the component initialises, also on watch and emit that to parent when created. This is what I want to DRY.

I've made a date/time picker in Vue before, which is kind of similar to your Calendar component in that there is a container component (DateTimePicker) which has 2 child components (DatePicker and TimePicker). Only one of the child components is visible at a time depending on whether the date or time is being edited.

I think it would be better to restructure how your components share data. It sounds to me like the child components are tightly coupled to the Calendar component (which is fine). I'm not sure if your Calendar component is meant for user input (can the user choose a date?), or only to display a particular date.

Why is it the responsibility of the child component to determine the title? The same Date is shared across each child component, so the Calendar component can easily determine the title depending on which child component is visible, something like:

```
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="cal-title">{{ title }}</div>
  <day v-if="view === 'day'" :value="date" @input="onInput"></day>
  <week v-if="view === 'week'" :value="date" @input="onInput"></week>
  <month v-if="view === 'month'" :value="date" @input="onInput"></month>
</div>
```

```
{
  props: ['date'],

  data() {
    return {
      view: 'day',
      // This component has no internal state for the date
    };
  },

  computed: {
    title() {
      switch (this.view) {
        case 'day': return this.date.format('day'); break;
        case 'week': return this.date.format('week'); break;
        case 'month': return this.date.format('month'); break;
      }
    },
  },

  methods: {
    onInput(date) {
      this.$emit('input', date);
    },
  },
}
```